# Mark version for backward compatibility execution of test cases

Tags: robotframework, versioning, backwards-compatibility

I have a set of test cases, some of them have evolved as the software releases came out. I need to maintain backward compatiility, so I need to be able to execute all tests compatible with a specific version of the software. I thought of using tags to check if a test case is compatible or not, but it doesn't work so well... Imagine the following test cases:

```
TC1 - v1.0
   [tags]  version=1.0
   ...

TC1 - v2.0
   [tags]  version=3.0
   ...

TC2 - v1.0
   [tags]  version=2.0
   ...
```

Right now, let's say I'm testing version 2.2 of my software.
I would like to run robot framework that way:

`robot -i version<=2.2 myTestSuite.robot`

I don't think that's possible.. so what's the proper way of handling this?
Looking forward to your suggestions!